# Definition of a TM accepting a word

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

The following is a quote from Sipser's "Introduction to the theory of computation"

> A Turing machine $M$ accepts input $w$ if a sequence of configurations
>   $C_{1}, C_{1}, \ldots , C_{k}$  exists, where
>
> 1. $C_{1}$ is the start configuration of $M$ on input $w$,
> 2. Each $C_{i}$ yields $C_{i+1}$ , and
> 3. $C_{k}$ is an accepting configuration.

The "if a sequence of configurations $C_{1}, C_{1}, \ldots , C_{k}$  exists" is a bit confusing. This is a deterministic TM, so there is only one sequence of configurations for a given machine and word, right? For instance, wouldn't the following do as a definition?

> A Turing machine $M$ accepts input $w$ if the state in the final configuration in $M$'s run on $w$ is an accepting state

Obviously, one has to formally define first what *the run* of a machine on a given word means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons to use this kind of definition:

1. It is a formal way to define the run of the machine.
2. It generalizes to the nondeterministic setting.

In the deterministic setting, an equivalent definition would be:

> Define a (possibly finite) sequence $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ as follows:
>
> 1. $C_1$ is the start configuration of $M$ on input $w$,
> 2. For $i \geq 1$, $C_{i+1}$ is the unique configuration yielded by $C_i$, if such a configuration exists.
>
> The machine $M$ accepts the input $w$ if the sequence is finite, and the last configuration is accepting.

This is not dramatically better than the quoted definition, and it doesn't generalize to the nondeterministic setting. It is a matter of taste which of the two to prefer.

Comment: Not better in terms of compactness, but more intuitive and unambiguous ("*The* sequence" as opposed to "*A* sequence"). Anyway, thanks for clarifying.